# Unable to catch JS error showing up in chrome's console.log

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, graphael, console.log

It would be great if there is a solution to the below problem, or else please tell me how I can simply catch the error coming up in my chrome's console.log. I have tried try-catch and window.onerror in my code but in vain.

I am trying to render an SVG chart ([gRaphael dotchart](http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.dotchart)) inside a 'hidden div'. But this throws up an error `Error: Problem parsing d="L0,0.001"` in my chrome console. When I click on this error, the console window takes me to the top of the html file where the error occurred, instead of the exact line in the client code or gRaphael library code. The error actually originates where the function `dotchart` gets called on the `Raphael` object (r.dotchart(...)). Strangely everything works perfectly fine when the div is 'not hidden'.

Thanks

Comment: try window.alert on line by line

Comment: occurs at the line where `dotchart` method is called on Raphael object (eg: r.dotchart(...)). Everything within the dotchart function is obfuscated library code. Can I catch this error globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting Chrome to Pause on uncaught exceptions? To do this, set the tri-state 'Pause on exceptions' button to the purple like colour:

[image]